# Pass extra variable to CFC for DB filter for Jqueryui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coldfusion

I have a jQueryUI autocomplete working, but realized that the data set is a little too big to look through without an additional filter.  I'm looking for a series of 'Products', but need to further pare the list by filtering on 'Product Family'.

I'm using ColdFusion as the back end, so I pass the lookup values to a CFC that queries an Oracle database.

What I've come up with (may be a better solution, I'm just not thinking of it) is to have a select with the 'Product Families'. I want to pass that `product_family_id` back to the CFC with the search term, using the `product_family_id` as a filter in the query. Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // autocomplete function   
    $("#primary_failing_product").autocomplete({

        source: "../../cfc/mwwf_software.cfc?method=lookup_product"
        select: function(event,ui) {
            $("#uid").val(ui.item.id)
        },
        search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = ( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;

                }

        }
    });

    // clear search box and hidden uid box
    $("#primary_failing_product").change(function(e) {
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            $("#uid").val("")
        };
    });
})
```

Here is the cfc:

```
<cffunction name="lookup_product" access="remote" returnformat="json">
    <cfargument name="term" required="yes" />

    <cfset prod_array = ArrayNew(2) />

    <!--- Do search --->
    <cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="data" maxrows="20">
        SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT, PRODUCT_ID
        FROM  BEMS_ENGAGEMENT_DETAILS_VW
        WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT IN ('MWWF', 'HCCB') 
        AND   PRODUCT IS NOT NULL 
        AND   LOWER(PRODUCT) LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="%#ARGUMENTS.term#%" />
        ORDER BY PRODUCT
    </cfquery>

    <!--- Build result array --->
    <cfloop query="data">
        <cfset prod_struct = StructNew() />
        <cfset prod_struct['id'] = product_id />
        <cfset prod_struct['label'] = product />

        <cfset ArrayAppend(prod_array, prod_struct) />
    </cfloop>

    <!--- And return it --->
    <cfreturn prod_array />
</cffunction>
```

That is just the working autocomplete lookup with too many values. I added select with the ID=product_family_id. I added the following to the javascript

```
var q_param
$('#product_family_id').on('change', function() {
        q_param = $("#product_family_id option:selected").val();
        alert(q_param)
```

This alerts me, just for testing, so I can see it is grabbing the correct `product_family_id`, but I can't figure out how to pass that value to the autocomplete function.

I adjusted the "source" to read,

```
../../cfc/mwwf_software.cfc?method=lookup_product&q_param=" + q_param
```

However, when looking in firebug, I can see the variable passed as an empty string breaking the cfc.

Is there a better way to handle this or is there a way to pull the updated q_param into the autocomplete widget to pass to the cfc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise using `source: function(){}` as an alternative method. For example:

```
$("#primary_failing_product").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
    $.getJSON("../../cfc/mwwf_software.cfc", {
      method: "lookup_product",
      q_param: $("#product_family_id").val(),
      term: request.term
    }, response);
  },
  select: function(event,ui) {
    $("#uid").val(ui.item.id)
  },
  search: function() {
    var term = ( this.value );
    if ( term.length < 2 ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

See more: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

In this way, you can create your own GET request with multiple terms passed to your CF Script. As you can see, you can collect settings or values from other parts of the page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was so wrapped in that other paradigm, I couldn't see another way.